# Cannot run npm and bash from maven

Tags: maven, npm

I have installed nodejs (npm) and npm install grunt-cli on my ubuntu box. I have found the nice maven-ant-run configuration for maven:

https://gist.github.com/nadavdav/5308453

but when I run **mvn clean install** from command-line I get:

```
building:
     [echo] ---------------------------------------------------
     [echo] -- NPM INSTALL --
     [echo] ---------------------------------------------------
     [exec] /usr/bin/npm: npm: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
     [exec] /usr/bin/npm: npm: line 2: `;(function () { // wrapper in case we're in module_context mode'
```

Why does npm fail when running inside maven?

EDIT: I have now updated the config to:

```
<!-- <exec executable="bash" dir="${project.basedir}" osfamily="unix" -->
<!--    failonerror="true"> -->
<!--    <arg line="npm install" /> -->
<!-- </exec> -->

<!-- WORKING -->
     <exec executable="npm" dir="${project.basedir}" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="install" />
     </exec>
```

which works. But strange that it does not work when running the original version.

Comment: Thanks, solved my issue as well - would you mind posting your solution as an answer(and not as an edit of your question) and accepting this answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because in the first example, you were running 'bash' with the argument 'npm install', which is the same as running `bash npm install` on the commandline.  This tells bash to try to run 'npm' as a shell script, but the `npm` script in your path is javascript code.  Try it:

```
john-warden-mba-2012:nodetest john$ bash npm install
/opt/local/bin/npm: npm: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
/opt/local/bin/npm: npm: line 2: `;(function () { // wrapper in case we're in module_context mode'
```

Comment: got the point... but how to fix in ant? @u123 updates didn't work on my case.

Comment: but I am using <macrodef> though.